# My .htaccess rule is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want all my URL with matching pattern as

```
/released/2013/iron-man 
/released/2013/abc-of-death 
/released/2012/saw6
```

to be redirected to

```
/released/1.php
```

and I can the name as well.

I am adding this rule to my .htaccess file but its not working

```
RewriteRule ^released/([0-9]+)/?$ /released/1.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Firstly, what server and web server are you running on? Secondly is mod_rewrite enabled if you are using Apache?

Comment: yes i am using apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing question mark matches an optional ending / which is not what you want.

```
^released/([0-9]+)/iron-man$
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^released/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /released/1.php?id=$1+$2
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he won't want the matched movie name to show up as part of the `id` parameter.

Comment: I have added 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule ^released/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /released/1.php?id=$1+$2
</IfModule>
............ stil its showing "/released/2013/iron-man was not found on this server."

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you have `$` after second slash but you have movie name after 2nd slash like `iron-man` etc. Remove `$` since you are not matching it.

Make sure that mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(released)/([0-9]+)/ /$1/1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Why the `RewriteCond` lines in this case? Pretty pointless for a universal redirect - it will negatively impact performance because of the filesystem checks and serve no purpose.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: What if theere is a real directory `/released/100/` Shouldn't that be skipped from this this rule.

Comment: The question says *"all my URL"*. I'm just following what he said.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: `I'm just following what he said` Looking at OP's name I sense it is "she" :P Deepthi pls feel free to omit RewriteCond if you don't need them for some performance benefits.

Comment: I have added <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine on RewriteOptions inherit RewriteRule ^released/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /released/1.php?id=$1+$2 </IfModule> ............ stil its showing "/released/2013/iron-man was not found on this server."

Comment: @DeepthiKhandelwal: What happens when you open this URL: `/released/1.php?id=2013` in your browser?

Comment: as expected my php file is run

Comment: OK try out my suggested answer now and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

A `RewriteRule` which does not specify a specific external domain is always executed internally. To make it **redirect** as you ask add `[R=301]` at the end - or 302, 303 or 307 depending on which kind of redirect you require, but usually `301` is fine.

Besides that, the regular expression you wrote does not allow for extended URLs - remove the trailing `$`. After that the `/?` part is moot so you can remove it as well.

The resulting line would read:

```
RewriteRule ^released/([0-9]+) /released/1.php?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```